# Expect echo password in clear text

Tags: passwords, cygwin, expect, psftp

Automating **psftp** with **bash/expect** in **cygwin**.

I have a very minimal script file **yftp.exp** with code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn psftp unixftpsrvr
expect "login as: "
send "myID\r"
expect "Password:"
send "Passw0rd\r"
expect "psftp>"
```

the output:

> $ ./yftp.exp 
>   spawn psftp unixftpsrvr 
>   login as: myID 
>   Using keyboard-interactive authentication. 
>   Enter your UDS 
>   Password: **Passw0rd**
>
> Remote working directory is /home/myID 
>   psftp>

**The password is printed out as clear text!!!**

if I run the command directly with psftp. here are the output:

> $ psftp unixftpsrvr 
>   login as: myID 
>   Enter your UDS Password: 
>   
>  Remote working directory is /home/myID 
>  
>   psftp>

The password is not displayed at all.

This seems to be more an issue on the expect side.

I am not concerned the password in clear text in my expect script file, I am concerned the password in clear text in the output!

how can I supress the display of password in clear text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password may be sent too early before ECHO is turned off. So try adding `sleep 1` after `expect "Password:"`.

If that does not work then try like this:

```
expect "Password:"
log_user 0; # disable logging to stdout
send "password\r"
log_user 1
```